# How does one create a discrete function where the probability of an outcome continuously changes with respect to time?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, function-and-relation-composition

For example, a fair coin would have a sample space = {H, T}. A particular probability function could take on different probability values (in the interval $[0,1]$) relative to time, such function could be $\mathbb{P}(H) =|\sin{(t)}|$ with $t \in \mathbf{R}^+$, with of course $\mathbb{P}(T) = 1-|\sin{(t)}|$. I chose $|\sin{(t)}|$ so as for the function to lie between $0$ and $1$.

Supposing one picks, in intervals of time $n$ where $n= t_{1}-t_{0}$ between H or T with a probability equal to $\mathbb{P}(H) =|\sin{t}|$ and were to move up the $y$ axis by $1$ when H occurred, and $-1$ when T occurred (in intervals of n) what would be the function that links the continously changing probability function $\mathbb{P}(H) =|\sin{(t)}|$ with the interval n function, defined only at points n, so as to create a discrete function that maps the path of the coin tosses.

In other words, how does one create a discrete function where the probability of an outcome continuously changes with respect to time?

I apologize for the terribly explained question, i have tried my best, i will gladly answer any,very comprehensible, confusion.

Comment: You would just take the continuous function at those discrete times

Comment: For example define $P_n(H) = |sin(n)|, n = 1,2,3,...$

Comment: @Alborz I believe that would yield the probability of one of those outcomes, and the other by extension, but I fail to understand how to transform that probability into a realization (since both are possible other than at maxima and minima), that is, what function randomly selects with probability p(H) at t and p(T) at t, one of the two outcomes.

Comment: Yes! The distribution when 2 outcomes are possible with a given probability for each I believe

Comment: Ok maybe I'm misunderstanding the question but can you clarify what this part means "I fail to understand how to transform that probability into a realization"? And "what function randomly selects with probability p(H) at t and p(T) at t, one of the two outcomes" the function that was mentioned ($P_n(H) = |sin(n)|$) which is just your function taken at discrete values can be used for this

Comment: Of course! Say the intervals are 0.1 so $n_{1} = 0.1$, Abs(sin(0.1)) = 0.0998 roughly, so you would have that the probability for H is roughly 9.98% at that point, continuing like this you will have in your graph the probability for H at each interval n, but you'd like to make a function that picks H 9.98 times out of 100, when at (sin(0.1)), therefore one that goes up by 1 9.98 times out of 100, and down by 1 90.02 when P = (sin(0.1)). Is it understandable? Perhaps I'm not making sense. I want a function that picks either H or T with a given probability at time t and moves in either direction

Comment: Whatever function or sequence of functions this is would probably change its output with each iteration under what I was thinking, since it would pick with a given probability, and you could not (hopefully) know what outcome it will pick. I don't know if such function exists, but since rand() exists in programming, i thought it might originate from some mathematical function or sequence of functions. @Alborz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define:

$X_n = 1,$ with probability $p_n = |sin(n)|$

$X_n = -1,$ with probability $1-p_n = 1 - |sin(n)|$

where $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$

Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: Yeah! This is amazing, now how do you turn the Random variable $X_{n}$ into a realized variable, which will take on for example at $n_{1}$ x = 1, then at $n_{2}$ x = 0 $n_{3}$ x = 0 and so on and so forth (of course it will take on different values at each iteration). For example, what comes out when you draw a random function in programming, that takes out values from a normal distribution, for a given amount of times realizations, say n, which you can then repeat, and get a different sequence of realizations of length n. I think that I'm really asking "How do you make the random function?"

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the terminology "realized variable" but if I get your meaning, I think you are asking about the implementation of the variable defined in this way right? If so then for example, your function takes $n$ as the input, and you do a computation based on that $n$ to find $p_n$, which is then used as the input for the 'random function' or you can think of it as the 'coin flip' parameter *for just that particular $n$*.

Comment: Exactly! The implementation part! I understand how $p_{n}$ will be the input of such a random function, but I do not understand what this function is, and how it spews a binary answer, 1 or -1 in our case, given a certain probability, in other words, what is this random function that writes 1 or -1 with varying probabilities over time, and draws the path? Basically what actually draws something like Brownian motion, in a different way at each iteration, and how would it draw something that changes its probability function over time as supposed to normal Brownian motion? @Alborz

Comment: Well to partially answer "what is this random function that writes 1 or -1 with varying probabilities over time, and draws the path?" the Stochastic process with values $X_n$ that we have defined here does exactly do that. But I think you are asking about if this kind of construction has a name or is a well known or well studied thing which I'm pretty sure it is but I don't know the answer. Some names that do apply to this: $X_i's$ are all categorical random variables, and in particular, binary random variables, they are also discrete, and as you pointed out yourself [continued next comment]

Comment: [continuing previous comment] if $p_n$ was fixed (not changing with n) this would essentially be the core of the discrete approximation model to a Brownian Motion, but as $p_n$ is not fixed I'm not sure if it can be considered BM or some variation of BM. Sorry

Comment: True, it could not because of this varying $p_{n}$ hence the contraposition with it, but I think that what I'm not understanding could be summed up as this, given what you wrote (which is super logical) how would I go about actually graphing it, really choosing among them? For example, I will be able to choose with a  probability of 0.4 Heads and 0.6 Tails at some point lets say, how do I actually choose among one of them and move in a certain direction (up in the y axis by 1 or down by 1). When $P = 1$ it is obvious, but what about when $P \neq 1$ , ?

Comment: This is a probabilistic model. You can only 'graph' particular outcomes. When P = 1 you have something deterministic

Comment: Oh, so you can not graph particular outcomes in a probabilistic model? I'm totally ignorant on this sorry.

Comment: @Kernos no you can, I said you can *only* graph particular outcomes of a probabilistic model

Comment: Particular outcomes as in only 1 or -1 or particular outcomes as in only when the probability function equals 1?

Comment: I'm saying you have this process where the values at each point $n = 1,2,3$ are not fixed and depend on the outcome of this experiment. If you run this experiment one time, you may have $X_1 = 1, X_2 = 1, X_3 = 0, ...$ etc. If you run it again, you may have $X_1 = 0, X_2 = 1, X_3 = 0$, etc. The values change each time. You can only graph a particular outcome of the experiment (a particular set of $X_i'$s)

Comment: Yes of course! I think I might have worded my question wrongly, but taking what you said, how can I create one specific sequence as the ones you made, like for example $X_{1}=1,X_{2}=1,X_{3}=0$, meaning how did you go from the definition you gave to this actual sequence, that's what I do not understand. What does the computer do for example to give that actual sequence once you define the probability function parameter and possible random variables (-1,1) as in our example.

Comment: Your question is a question of programming and not at all about math. There are *many* random number generation algorithms and the answer to the question you have depends entirely on the programming implementation of this definition along with the random number generation algorithm used by that program.

Comment: Understood, thank you however for the help!